# Не правильно работает делегатор (не могу импортировать из Qt EditRole

Tags: python, gui, pyqt6

Пытаюсь создать делегатор для таблицы, чтобы можно было вводить только цифры. Не могу понять, почему я не могу использовать EditRole из Qt. Может он был убран или переименован в 6 версии?

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QStyledItemDelegate, QLineEdit
from PyQt6.QtCore import QRegularExpression, Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QRegularExpressionValidator


#делегат для числовых значений
class NumericDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super(NumericDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QLineEdit):
            reg_ex = QRegularExpression("[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{,2}")
            validator = QRegularExpressionValidator(reg_ex, editor)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
        return editor
    
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        editor.setText(str(value))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = float(editor.text())
        model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)
```

Comment: Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole